# GitLab CI Visual Studio dependency from other repository

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, gitlab, pipeline

I have Visual Studio projects with this structure:

- Project A
- Project B

  - depends on Project A built exe file (it iherits one interface)

Both projects has repository on GitLab. Project A finished pipeline with required exe file in artifact.
Project B fails on pipeline, because MSBuild cannot find reference to exe file.

What should I do in the script for Project B to download latest artifact (I already have URL for that), set the reference while building on build server and compile project properly?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do in the script for Project B to download latest artifact (I already have URL for that), set the reference while building on build server and compile project properly?

Yes, you should set project B reference project A. With this settings, Visual Studio/MSBuild will be smart to build the project A first, then build the project B and copy the Project A built exe file to the output folder.

Note: When you build the project on the server, you should build the solution file instead of project B or project A directly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But what if projects are in different solutions?

Comment: @Sha-1, If projects are in different solutions, you could add project A to the solution of project B or you need to build the solution A first, then use a copy task to copy the .exe file before you build the solution B